# Как вырезать сохранить и вставить массив при изменении условия вычисляемого метода computed?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Я новичок во VUE и мне нужна ваша помощь.
По условию у меня есть некий массив данных, состоящий из объектов.
Мне нужно отслеживать состояние условия при изменении которого массив должен быть полностью удален и сохранен.
А при удовлетворяющих условиях этот массив нужно вернуть обратно.
Я делал это в методе computed, но у меня ничего не получилось, подскажите как это можно реализовать?
Вот пример из кода.

```
  computed: {
    PURCHASED_EQUIPMENT() {
      let items = [] 
      if (this.$parent.project.UF_INDUSTRY_ID !== 21) {
        [...items] = this.project.PURCHASED_EQUIPMENT.items.splice(0)
      } 
      else if (this.$parent.project.UF_INDUSTRY_ID === 21) {
        this.project.PURCHASED_EQUIPMENT.items.push(items)
      }
```

Comment: `this.$parent.project.UF_INDUSTRY_ID` - не делайте так. Таким кодом, Вы навеки связываете родителя и ребенка. Ребенок без родителя не сможет существовать. лучше передайте необходимое значение через `props`. Либо же, отправляйте его в store

Answer (score 2):

Так как в условиях задачи небыло ничего, про то что массив может наполнятся после того как его почистили, то проще всего сделать вот так

```
data() {
  return {
    arr: [
      { foo: true, boo: false },
      { foo: false, boo: true },
      { foo: true, boo: false },
    ],
    condition: false,
  };
},
computed: {
  arrResult: function () {
    if (this.condition) return this.arr;
    return [];
  },
},
```

Оригинальный массив вообще не трогаем и просто выдаем в `arrResult` в зависимости от `condition` оригинальный или пустой массив.